# Can we add an image in Extjs Scatter chart series?

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4.2

I could see in ExtJs scattered cart we could use different marker configs to show cross,circle,square etc. But instead of that can we show an image or glyph there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can show image instead of circle, square etc.

You will need to override **Ext.chart.Shape** to add additional image types for your series. You can use those defined types in **markerConfig** of series.

Basically you will need to define your own shape type which will be created with [Ext.draw.Sprite](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite) in chart.

Here is a working example with ExtJS 4.2.1.x:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.override(Ext.chart.Shape, {
            newPhone: function (surface, opts) {
                return surface.add(Ext.apply({
                    type: 'image',
                    src: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/igh0zt/ios7-style-metro-ui/512/MetroUI-Other-Phone-icon.png',
                    x: opts.x,
                    y: opts.y,
                    width: 14,
                    height: 14
                }, opts));
            },
            oldPhone: function (surface, opts) {
                return surface.add(Ext.apply({
                    type: 'image',
                    src: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/communication-1/100/old_phone-512.png',
                    x: opts.x,
                    y: opts.y,
                    width: 14,
                    height: 14
                }, opts));
            }
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
            fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'metric one',
                'data1': 10,
                'data2': 12,
                'data3': 14,
                'data4': 8,
                'data5': 13
            }, {
                'name': 'metric two',
                'data1': 7,
                'data2': 8,
                'data3': 16,
                'data4': 10,
                'data5': 3
            }, {
                'name': 'metric three',
                'data1': 5,
                'data2': 2,
                'data3': 14,
                'data4': 12,
                'data5': 7
            }, {
                'name': 'metric four',
                'data1': 2,
                'data2': 14,
                'data3': 6,
                'data4': 1,
                'data5': 23
            }, {
                'name': 'metric five',
                'data1': 27,
                'data2': 38,
                'data3': 36,
                'data4': 13,
                'data5': 33
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            animate: true,
            theme: 'Category2',
            store: store,
            axes: [{
                type: 'Numeric',
                position: 'left',
                fields: ['data2', 'data3'],
                title: 'Sample Values',
                grid: true,
                minimum: 0
            }, {
                type: 'Category',
                position: 'bottom',
                fields: ['name'],
                title: 'Sample Metrics'
            }],
            series: [{
                type: 'scatter',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'oldPhone'
                },
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data2'
            }, {
                type: 'scatter',
                markerConfig: {
                    type: 'newPhone'
                },
                axis: 'left',
                xField: 'name',
                yField: 'data3'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**Example Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29rm

Comment: Thank you Saurabh. It worked!. Considering the quality drop in image, i wanted to draw a path there. So i did few modification. Please find the example. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29uj. But the legends are coming awkward. Is there any way we could customize the legend.

Comment: Also i observed the we cannot add tooltip's for these custom sprites!

Comment: Use legend property for legend config. 

legend: { position: 'bottom',  padding: 25, margin: 0 } should fix..

Example fiddle:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29ur